# ASMX Web Service authentication

Tags: .net-2.0, asmx

I want to authenticate web service user on first web method call only & use his identity for other web method calls.

How web service maintain the user identity?

Answer (score 0):

ASMX web services only support the types of authentication directly supported by IIS.

Alternatively, you could implement your own authentication using SOAP Headers, but then your authentication code has to be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a session using 2.0 or a cookie and than passing the data will be easy.
Let me know.